# problem with installation matlab

Tags: command-line, software-installation, matlab

I want to install maltab to 32-bit version , so i follow the instructions , and i have write this command `sudo /media/MATHWORKS_R2012A/install -glnx86 -v` but it give me `sudo: /media/MATHWORKS_R2012A/install: command not found` , so what is the solution of this problem .

Comment: post the output of `file /media/MATHWORKS_R2012A/install`

Comment: @AvinashRaj this is the output : `media/MATHWORKS_R2012A/install: ERROR: cannot open ` `/media/MATHWORKS_R2012A/install' (No such file or directory)``

Comment: @raaz `ls: cannot access media/MATHWORKS_R2012A/: No such file or directory`

Comment: did you mount the matlab file?

Comment: @raaz , the output of `ls /media/MATHWORKS_R2012A/` is `ls: cannot access /media/MATHWORKS_R2012A/: No such file or directory ,and the output of `ls /media` is `hassan`
`

Comment: @AvinashRaj , how do i mount the matlab file?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I have got his problem I think , previously /media will have mounted but right now inside media there is username too

Comment: you open file browser go to *mathworks_2012a* folder find *install* file and right clik it open *properties* and see path correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These instructions assume you have inserted a CD and that has been mounted as:

```
/media/MATHWORKS_R2012A/
```

That's clearly not happening so there's something going on. More modern copies of Ubuntu will use `/media/$USER/MATHWORKS_R2012A/` but instead of scatter-gunning this, just open up the file manager go to the CD/DVD drive and see where it's mounted.

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> will give you the path (repeat to hide it). Then just `cd` into that path in a terminal (remembering to quote or escape any spaces or weird characters) and then run:

```
./install -glnx86 -v
```

---

Obviously if you aren't using a CD (network mount or whatever) the same approach applies. Find out where the files are, go to that location and call the binary.

Comment: I have search for `MATHWORKS_R2012A` File or path , and it's seems that the file or path it does not exist !

Comment: That's what I'm saying, don't bother looking for a specific path, look at the CD (or source) you've actually got and get the path from that.